# What is Dash(-) actually in unix or linux?

Tags: linux, dash

It's been While since i'm using `dash(-)` in unix command. But have never found out what exactly is this.

Have searched at some place it says . It mean `stdin/stdout` when used in end of command or like  `echo hello >` - .

For example When i write `grep -i` it checks with ignore case. (so i think it get argument here as -i)

While if sometime when filename or folder name begins with `-folderName` i need to run `rm -f -- -folderName`

What exactly this dash is can someone explain it in simple term.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the command.

By convention, a standalone dash in place of a filename, would mean 'stdin' or 'stdout'.

E.g.

```
tar cvfz - ./path-to-tar | ssh somehost tar xvfz -
```

However this is merely a standard sort of a flag for this purpose - what it *actually* means is 'whatever the person who wrote the command thought it should'.

Comment: To elaborate perhaps a bit too far: some programs (`optipng` for example?) don't give it any special meaning at all, and will actually just look for a file called `-` in the current directory.